# error ModelForm has no model class specified in django

Tags: python, django, modelform

i am working with django and i have the form:

```
from django import forms
from clientes.administrativo.models import Customer

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Formulario para el catálogo de clientes"""
    model = Customer
    class Meta:
        fields = ['code_customers', 'trade_name', 'legal_name','name_owner',
        'name_manager','address','email','phone','city','post_code','customers_type',
        'locked','special_credit','tax_exempt','distributor','customers_subgroup',
        'final_consumer','retention_agent','nit','contac']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
     


    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            model.save()
        return model
```

But when i try to do this save() with this method:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'PUT', 'GET'])
@permission_classes([LoginRequired])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def register_customer(request, format=None):
    customerFM = CustomerForm(request.data)
    if customerFM.is_valid():
        customerFM.save()
        return {'success': True,'message': ''}
    return {'success': False,'message': 'Hubo un error, por favor intente nuevamente..'}
```

I get the error `ModelForm has no model class specified`...

Any help with this? Thank you!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the model class inside the `Meta`:

```
class Meta:
  model = Customer
  fields =[..]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `model=Customer` should be inside the `Meta` class.